# Filtering and joining data in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two sets of data, and I'd like to left_join the results frame with the scores frame (but only where the rank is equal to two).

I assume there's an easier way than filtering the scores dataframe, joining the data and the adding that frame to the rank 1 and 3 results.

Can anyone suggest a quicker way of doing this?

My inputs are:

```
scores = structure(list(Name = c("Frank", "John", "Mary", "Sue", "Tony", 
"Frank", "John", "Mary", "Sue", "Tony", "Frank", "John", "Mary", 
"Sue", "Tony"), Rank = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Score = c(51L, 55L, 57L, 75L, 52L, 40L, 
33L, 32L, 44L, 31L, 15L, 12L, 15L, 10L, 17L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

and

```
results = structure(list(Name = c("Frank", "John", "Mary", "Sue", "Tony"
), Result = c(250L, 210L, 280L, 260L, 100L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

and I'm trying to get this:

```
output = structure(list(Name = c("Frank", "John", "Mary", "Sue", "Tony", 
"Frank", "John", "Mary", "Sue", "Tony", "Frank", "John", "Mary", 
"Sue", "Tony"), Rank = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Score = c(64L, 69L, 50L, 57L, 72L, 40L, 
46L, 47L, 41L, 38L, 29L, 19L, 25L, 11L, 19L), Results = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 250L, 210L, 280L, 260L, 100L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

Thanks.

Comment: So simply merge and replace?, i.e. `scores %>% left_join(results, by = 'Name') %>% mutate(Result = replace(Result, Rank != 2, NA))`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that all you need to do is merge and filter on `Rank`, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)

scores %>% 
 left_join(results, by = 'Name') %>% 
 mutate(Result = replace(Result, Rank != 2, NA))
```

which gives,

> ```
>     Name Rank Score Result
> 1  Frank    1    51     NA
> 2   John    1    55     NA
> 3   Mary    1    57     NA
> 4    Sue    1    75     NA
> 5   Tony    1    52     NA
> 6  Frank    2    40    250
> 7   John    2    33    210
> 8   Mary    2    32    280
> 9    Sue    2    44    260
> 10  Tony    2    31    100
> 11 Frank    3    15     NA
> 12  John    3    12     NA
> 13  Mary    3    15     NA
> 14   Sue    3    10     NA
> 15  Tony    3    17     NA
> ```